# Array find not working when search again object.value. But its working when specifying value directly

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm facing a weird issue.

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedBudget.year" name="" class="form-control" id="">
                  <option value="2020">2020</option>
                  <option value="2021">2021</option>
                </select>
```

and here is my function to search for a value based on the year selected.

```
  addBudget(){
    alert(this.selectedBudget.year);//shows 2021
    alert(this.locations.find(p=>p.year=== 2021).locationName); here it shows the location name
    alert(this.locations.find(p=>p.year=== this.selectedBudget.year).locationName); //here it trigger error
/*     let rc = this.locations.find(x => x.locationName === this.selectedBudget.locationName && 
      x.year === this.selectedBudget.year).cost; //resource cost
      alert(rc); */
      console.info(this.locations);

  }
```

As I mentioned in the internal comments after each alerts, it triggers an error **Cannot read property locationName of undefined**. But the weird thing is its working the line just above that.

So 2021 when I specify as value directly it returns but when checking against the property its not working.

Is there is anything wrong with the way I specified ngModel. Mine is a pre-populated dropdown.

Comment: is this.selectedBudget.year an integer or string?

Comment: Its a number. Initially I pass it to the class constructor and its 2020

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting string values by doing `value="2021"`. This means the strict equality comparison of `p.year === 2021` fails because the types are different.

Instead, bind the numeric values to the options using `[ngValue]`. This will mean that the selected value is now numeric, and your strict equality check will pass.

```html
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedBudget.year" class="form-control">
  <option [ngValue]="2020">2020</option>
  <option [ngValue]="2021">2021</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Oh man.. you are awesome.. it worked great.. I am a very beginner with Angular. Had no idea about any difference between value and ngvalue